# How do I do OAuth 2 authentication for a Flutter app to access Google APIs?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-oauth, flutter-dependencies

I'd like my Flutter app (web, iPhone, and Android) to do OAuth 2 authentication to access Google APIs.

The documentation is a mad maze of explaining the very basic idea of authentication without providing actual steps. Anything claiming to be a "how to get started" lists high level steps and then points at other documentation that points at other documentation. At one point, I saw single line of code, but there was no explanation how I get a UI to show the user from that line of code. When I find articles on the web for how to get started, it's for third party APIs, not Google APIs.

Can someone give me the command line for what dependencies to add to my flutter project and code to copy and paste for a "Hello World" OAuth2 authentication?

Comment: Have you tried the official flutter tutorial on google apis. It was relatively simple to follow: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/google-apis

Comment: I've tried that documentation. At step 3, it says: "Follow the instructions provided by package:google_sign_in to allow a user to authenticate." So I followed the link there. There were no clear instructions at the destination, only links elsewhere. It's like all the other documentation pages that I found. They seem easy but leave important bits out.

Comment: FYI: I've figured it out. However, there was a huge amount of ambiguous steps involved that I'm not sure I can reproduce correctly. There was a lot of configuration on the server involved that was unclear. I had to import different libraries because the default ones didn't work out of the box, but Google had patches.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Can you please share some insight on how you did it? What libraries did you use to make it work? How did you make it work?

Comment: The documentation here is roughly the right thing, but there were multiple steps unclear/incomplete/confusing: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/google-apis

step #1: This step doesn't tell you what scopes you need or can get or mean. This one was what I needed: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' Also, the process for review is very confusing. 

Step #3: I thought the sample code returns a UI object that I have to somehow mount. It doesn't. It pops up its own UI.

Step #4: The described method was missing until I noticed that I had to install another dependency.